# Spring Boot Custom HTTP EXCEPTION

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this method to handle all request header missing exceptions, but in one controller is expected to receive a json as body. If it is a invalid json or is null, it drops a exception with custom messages:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ServletRequestBindingException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
public final ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleHeaderException(Exception ex) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse("Bad Request", details), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

> {
>       "message": "Bad Request",
>       "details": [
>           "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   packages.fazerLogin(packages.BodyLogin) throws java.io.IOException"
>       ] }

---

> {
>       "message": "Bad Request",
>       "details": [
>           "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
>   ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at
>   [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 3]"
>       ] }

But I don't want a long message such as above. Just "Required request body" or "JSON parse error" is just fine. I want to know what can I do.

My controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "v1/token", consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<TokenOutputDto> doLogin(@RequestBody @Valid BodyLogin body) throws IOException {
    return authenticationModel.auth(body.getEmail(), body.getPassword());
}
```

Also, should I create a @ExceptionHandler method to each one of the possibles exceptions (HttpClientErrorException, HttpServerErrorException etc)? It will be a bad pratice, because the code will repeat almost identically...

Comment: no, if you need to handle each exception differently then you need different methods

Answer (score 0):

You can handle those exception handlers in your method by following way:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ServletRequestBindingException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
public final ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleHeaderException(Exception ex) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    if (ex instanceof IOException ) {
        if (ex.getCause() instanceof JsonParseException) {
            details.add("JSON parse error");
        } else {
            details.add("Required request body");
        }
    } else {
        details.add(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse("Bad Request", details), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: if (ex instanceof IOException ) will always be false, cause ex is a Exception... right?

Comment: Ok so you should check its cause, yes, how is it working? the exceptions are wrapped by some point then you can check if that exception is wrapped 2nd level else third level until you find it